# Loading native C library from Objective-C in Flutter plugin

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter, native

I have a native C library `(.so)` build in versions for android and iOS. I want them to be used in a flutter app I am building. 
For android I use System.loadLibrary() in Java to load the file (wrapped in `JNI`) and it is included via the `Gradle` build `system/CMake`. 
But how do I get the same for iOS in objective C ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I can use dlopen() on the library and then dlsym() every single function to get their symbol into the app at runtime. Seems pretty dump but I guess it could work (when I at some point have convinced the buildsystem to include the lib into the actual package it builds.

Comment: Hi @kimusan could you please elaborate more you answer, i have the same question. thanks